# Регулярное выражение для сопоставления URL и маршрута

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Требуется помощь с изменением регулярки для маршрутизации.

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))', array(
        'id'       => '[\d]+',
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'id'     => NULL,
    ));
```

Данному маршруту соответствуют URL вида `/`, `/product/`, `/product/add/`, `/product/add/123`. `(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))` - выражение, за ним следует массив выражений для проверки на соответствие параметров, в `defaults` переданы значения параметров по умолчанию.

Как изменить маршрут:

```
Route::set('pages', '(<lang>/<slug>(/<subrequest>))', array(
        'lang'       => '[a-z]{2}',
        'slug'       => '[\w\-]+',
        'subrequest' => '[\w\-\/]+',
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'Page',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'lang'       => 'en',
        'slug'       => 'home',
        'subrequest' => NULL,
    ));
```

Так, чтобы:

- `lang` мог быть задан или опущен
- `slug` мог быть задан или опущен
- `subrequest` мог быть задан(если задан `slug`) или опущен

т.е. под данный маршрут подходили бы ссылки: `/`, `/en/`, `/en/contacts/`, `/contacts/`, `/en/contacts/config/meta/` и `/contacts/config/meta/`

Answer (score 1):

Для Вашего случая лучше использовать 2 роута. Не получится выкинуть первый параметр чтобы остались вторые и третьи.

В таком раскладе могут существовать либо все, либо обязательно 2 первых параметра, и необязательный третий.

```
(<lang>/<slug>(/<subrequest>))
```

Нужно сделать 1 обязательным, второй по необходимости и третий тоже в последнюю очередь

```
<lang>(/<slug>(/<subrequest>))
```

И создать второй роут ниже, так как он более общий, но уже без языковой переменной

```
<slug>(/<subrequest>)
```

Ничего страшного нет если будет использоваться на 1 роут больше, за то Ваша задача будет решена, тем более что когда разработка закончится и приложение приобретет нужный вид и функционал нужно будет кэшировать роуты, чтобы сократить нагрузку. Кэшировать надо в любом случае если роутов более 15 - 20 штук

А по идее если нужно использовать языки то лучше языковую переменную оставлять всегда обязательной.

```
<lang>(/<slug>(/<subrequest>))
```

Можно попробовать еще вот таким способом задать, только в этом случае будет лучше прописать в диапазоне допустимых значений варианты языков:

```
Route::set('pages', '(<lang>/)(<slug>(/<subrequest>))', array(
    'lang'       => '(ru|en)', // и так далее
    'slug'       => '[\w\-]+',
    'subrequest' => '[\w\-\/]+',
));
```

Но почему-то мне кажется Kohana не поймет такого издевательства над ее логикой =)

Comment: обязательным язык сделать нельзя, т.к. данный роут не будет срабатывать для главной страницы. зачем мне кажется тут все-таки можно обойтись одним роутом и сказывается мое незнание regexp